# Одинаковые результаты Asyncio и Синхронного кода

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, asyncio, асинхронность

написал код, запустил, результаты примерно одинаковы:
`4.6002631187438965 ----- 7.045402765274048`.

Почему так, ведь, я думаю asyncio запускает всё вместе? А синхронный код в данном случае просто перебирает все по очереди.

```
import asyncio
from time import time


predictions = []


async def is_simple(num):
    global predictions
    dividers_list = []
    for divider in range(1, num + 1):
        if num % divider == 0:
            dividers_list.append(divider)
    if len(dividers_list) == 2: predictions.append([num, dividers_list])


async def starter(ranges):
    tasks_list = []
    for num in range(ranges):
        tasks_list.append(asyncio.create_task(is_simple(num)))
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks_list)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    t0 = time()
    loop.run_until_complete(starter(ranges = 10000))
    print(predictions)
    print(time() - t0)


t0 = time()
snums = []
for element in range(10000):
    slist_nums = []
    for divider in range(1, element + 1):
        if element % divider == 0:
            slist_nums.append(divider)
    if len(slist_nums) == 2:
        snums.append([element, slist_nums])


print(snums)
print(time() - t0)

print(f'{len(snums)} ----- {len(predictions)}')
```

Comment: В is_simple нет await. Запускается параллельно, но is_simple не дает шанса поработать кому то еще, пока сама не отработает до конца

Comment: @vitidev сработает ли, если я добавлю туда asyncio.sleep(0)?

Comment: Не сработает. is_simple что-то там считает локально и в конце модифицирует predictions. все эти асинк функции планируются на старт одна за одной. А значит и `predictions.append([num, dividers_list])` тоже отработают в том же порядке. Нет причин чтобы вычисление dividers_list позже запущенной таски отработало раньше ранее запущенной. async это не многопоточность

Comment: @vitidev В таком случае что необходимо поменять, для того, чтобы достичь поставленной задачи, используя asyncio?

Comment: @vitidev или же эта задача для тредов, ибо нет ввода данных?

Comment: Но ведь треды тоже работают поочередно, каким образом тогда решить это?

Comment: Нет. треды работают параллельно. Просто из-за GIL в один момент работает один тред. Но рантайм сам переключает на другой тред через какое то время, а нагрузка проца не постоянна, поэтому выполнение какого то треда может немного обогнать другие. В async переключение происходит добровольно и пока не дойдет до нужной точки - переключения не будет. Если вставить `await asyncio.sleep(random.uniform(0.01, 0.1))` перед `if len(dividers_list)` то тогда время модификации `predictions` не будет последовательным ибо таски будут заканчиваться в рэндомном порядке. Правда итераций нужно поменьше сделать

Comment: @vitidev Вставил ```asyncio.sleep...```, стало работь еще медленнее. Почему - понятно, но через какую систему можно попробовать пойти на решение?

Comment: Знать бы что решается. Если ускорить, то только через процессы. Потому что задача cpu-bound (использует только cpu и не ждет ответа от сети или еще чего, чтобы дать в это время поработать другим). Треды только медленнее будет из-за GIL, а async вообще не про это. Так что ProcessPoolExecutor вам в руки - использование пула выгоднее создания процессов вручную из-за необходимости частого создания процессов в вашей задаче.

Comment: @vitidev Решается процесс обучения асинхронному программированию. Задача выдуманная. Для чего же тогда asyncio?

Comment: для задач "я тут жду ответа из сети, базы данных, файла, просто sleep и потому пусть поработают другие, а я свое продолжение запланирую на момент поступления этих данных (await). Так что вы меня там разбудите в нужный момент (await) чтобы продолжить выполнение с этой точки ожидания". То есть в задаче должны быть моменты, когда приходится просто ждать и нечем занять cpu - и на это время можно переключить на другую задачу.

Comment: `await asyncio.sleep(0)`  если хочется переключения тасков в произвольном месте. Но таски запускаются последовательно а не паралельно!

Answer (score 2):

`asyncio` не запускает всё вместе. Оно лишь прерывает функцию в момент ожидания `await` и в это время выполняет другие таски. Возвращается в функцию если ожидание завершено в момент когда другой таск прервется на `await` .

Чтоб ускорить Ваш код нужно использовать [ProcessPoolExecutor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor) в асинкио или обычный `multiprocessing`.

`asyncio` нужен для того чтоб выполнять таски пока что-то скачивается по сети, из базы данных или какой-то таск ждет таймера.

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых саму вашу задачу можно ускорить в несколько раз, если добавить условие досрочного прерывания цикла такого вида:

```
        if num % divider == 0:
            # Если уже есть два делителя, то их будет 3
            # и дальше можно уже не проверять
            if len(dividers_list) >= 2:
                break
            dividers_list.append(divider)
```

Во-вторых асинхронность, как вам уже сказали в комментариях - для **IO bound** задач, т.е. задач, ожидающих окончания ввода-вывода. Для задач вида **CPU bound**, т.е. занимающихся вычислениями, как ваша задача, нужно использовать многопоточность. Хотя не факт, что в питоне это даст какой-то эффект из-за `GIL`, нужно проверять. И в этом случае нужно избавляться от `global` переменных, результат из функции нужно возвращать в явном виде и потом собирать его в список. Иначе, например, при использовании мультипроцессности, у вас не получится единый результат - у каждого процесса будет своя отдельная глобальная переменная, в которую он и добавит данные.